# is it possible to test the difference of the difference between means in a linear model with interactions?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, interaction, group-differences, lm

### Data

I am working in R and I have continuous data identified by two factors: class and subclass

```
library(ggplot2)
library(multcomp)

model_data<- data.frame("class"= rep(c("X", "Y"), each=90),
                        "subclass"= rep(c("a", "b", "c"), 60))

coefs<- c(0, 0.4, 0.9, 0, 1, 0.9)

set.seed(25)
rnorms<- sapply(coefs, function(x) rnorm(n = 30, sd = 1, mean = x))
colMeans(rnorms)

model_data$value<- NA
model_data$value[model_data$class=="X" & model_data$subclass=="a"]<- rnorms[,1]
model_data$value[model_data$class=="X" & model_data$subclass=="b"]<- rnorms[,2]
model_data$value[model_data$class=="X" & model_data$subclass=="c"]<- rnorms[,3]
model_data$value[model_data$class=="Y" & model_data$subclass=="a"]<- rnorms[,4]
model_data$value[model_data$class=="Y" & model_data$subclass=="b"]<- rnorms[,5]
model_data$value[model_data$class=="Y" & model_data$subclass=="c"]<- rnorms[,6]
```

### Desired comparisons

For this data, I want to test whether "*the difference between subclasses **a** and **b** in class **X***" is significantly different to "*the difference between subclasses **a** and **b** in class **Y***", and other similar hypotheses. To be more clear (see attached plot), I want test the difference between 1 and 1.1, the difference between 2 and 2.2, and the difference between 3 and 3.3.
[image: observed values and desired contrasts]

### Proposed method

To do that, I built a bifactorial lineal model: $u = \beta_{0} + \beta_{1}Y + \beta_{2}b + \beta_{3}c + \beta_{4}Yb + \beta_{5}Yc$

```
model<- lm(value ~ class * subclass, data = model_data)
model
# Call:
#   lm(formula = value ~ class * subclass, data = model_data)
# 
# Coefficients:
#   (Intercept)            classY         subclassb         subclassc  classY:subclassb  
# -0.18478           0.09683           0.33383           0.84767           0.75214  
# classY:subclassc  
# 0.14083
```

If I am interpreting things correctly, the comparisons I am interested in are:

- $[(Xa-Xb)-(Ya-Yb)]$ for (1) compared to (1.1)
- $[(Xa-Xc)-(Ya-Yc)]$ for (2) compared to (2.2)
- $[(Xb-Xc)-(Yb-Yc)]$ for (3) compared to (3.3)

Then, the resulting hypotheses can be derived as follows:

For the difference between (1) and (1.1):
$(Xa-Xb)-(Ya-Yb) = [\beta_{0}-(\beta_{0} + \beta_{2})] - [(\beta_{0} + \beta_{1}) - (\beta_{0} + \beta_{1} + \beta_{2} + \beta_{4})]$
$(Xa-Xb)-(Ya-Yb) = \beta_{4}$ 
$H_{0}(1): \beta_{4} = 0$

For the difference between (2) and (2.2):
$(Xa-Xc)-(Ya-Yc) = [\beta_{0}-(\beta_{0} + \beta_{3})] - [(\beta_{0} + \beta_{1}) - (\beta_{0} + \beta_{1} + \beta_{3} + \beta_{5})]$
$(Xa-Xc)-(Ya-Yc) = \beta_{5}$ 
$H_{0}(3): \beta_{5} = 0$

For the difference between (3) and (3.3):
$(Xb-Xc)-(Yb-Yc) = [(\beta_{0} + \beta_{2})-(\beta_{0} + \beta_{3})] - [(\beta_{0} + \beta_{1} + \beta_{2} + \beta_{4}) - (\beta_{0} + \beta_{1} + \beta_{3} + \beta_{5})]$
$(Xb-Xc)-(Yb-Yc) = -\beta_{4} + \beta_{5}$
$H_{0}(3): \beta_{5} -\beta_{4} = 0$

Then, to tests the contrasts I used the multicomp library:

```
contrast.names<- c("(Xa-Xb)-(Ya-Yb)", "(Xa-Xc)-(Ya-Yc)", "(Xb-Xc)-(Yb-Yc)")
contrast_matrix<- rbind(
  c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0),
  c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1),
  c(0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 1)
  )
row.names(contrast_matrix)<- contrast.names

contrasts<- glht(model = model, linfct = contrast_matrix)
summary(contrasts, test=adjusted("none"))
# Simultaneous Tests for General Linear Hypotheses
# 
# Fit: lm(formula = value ~ class * subclass, data = model_data)
# 
# Linear Hypotheses:
#                       Estimate  Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
# (Xa-Xb)-(Ya-Yb) == 0   0.7521     0.3405   2.209   0.0285 *
# (Xa-Xc)-(Ya-Yc) == 0   0.1408     0.3405   0.414   0.6797  
# (Xb-Xc)-(Yb-Yc) == 0  -0.6113     0.3405  -1.795   0.0744 .
# ---
#   Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
# (Adjusted p values reported -- none method)
```

### The questions

Finally, interpreting the coefficients, pvalues and plot, I can conclude that *"the difference between subclasses **a** and **b** is larger in class **Y** than in class **X**"*

1) Was this a proper way of testing the desired differences?, is there a better one?
2) Considering that the difference between subclasses **a** and **b** in class **X** is not significant ("subclassb" in table below), is the conclusion still valid?

```
summary(model)$coefficients
#                   Estimate   Std.Error  t value    Pr(>|t|)
# (Intercept)      -0.1847803  0.1702670 -1.0852388   0.279
# classY            0.0968255  0.2407939  0.4021095   0.688
# subclassb         0.3338348  0.2407939  1.3863925   0.167
# subclassc         0.8476750  0.2407939  3.5203345   0.001
# classY:subclassb  0.7521353  0.3405340  2.2086941   0.029
# classY:subclassc  0.1408272  0.3405340  0.4135481   0.680
```